# PHPExcell get cell value and cell color?

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

How to get cell values and cell colors from spreadsheet-reader-master or PHPExcell?

```
<?php

require('spreadsheet-reader-master/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php'); //spreadsheet-reader-master

require('spreadsheet-reader-master/SpreadsheetReader.php'); //spreadsheet-reader-master

$reader = new SpreadsheetReader('Book1.xlsx');   // xlsx file


foreach ($reader as $key ) {   
    //foreach loop 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($key);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require('./PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$tmpframe = './Book1.xlsx';
$exceReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpframe);
$excelObj = $exceReader->load($tmpframe);
$worksheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet();
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
// $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
// $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();


$rowl = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$coll = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
echo "number of rows---".$rowl."<br>";
echo "number of column---".$coll."<br>";

$rowdumy = 20;
    $crt = 'QT';
    $crt++;
    for ($row=1; $row <= $rowdumy; $row++) { 
        echo "<h6>number of-----".$row."</h5><br>";
        for ($i = 'A'; $i !== $crt; $i++){
        $cell = $worksheet->getCell($i.$row);
        $colurc = $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($i.$row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->getARGB();
        if($cell != '')
        {
            echo $cell."-[[".$colurc."]]";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Download first PHPExcel-1.8 ZIP file and Set "./PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php"  and run script.

Comment: if you want to get RGB color, just change `getRGB()`.